# Can I call functions across programming language boundaries using function pointer?

Tags: c#, c++, function, function-pointers

A C# application has a static dependency on a C++ DLL. Lets say there is a function in C# application as below:

```
void foo(int a)
{
   Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

The C++ DLL has an exported function that looks like as below.

```
typedef void (*Func_t)(int);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void bar(Func_t f)
{
   f(5);
}
```

Can I call `bar()` function from the C# application and pass `foo()` as a parameter and expect '5' to be printed?

```
bar(foo);
```

Comment: You need to actually import the cpp method from c sharp will Dll import but It should work.

Comment: ok, I forgot to mention that this is assuming that I have imported the DLL function 'bar' in the C# application.

Comment: ok so why would there be any problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Define a delegate

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate void Func_t(int a);
```

Import the function

```
[DllImport(...)]
static extern void bar(Func_t f);
```

Usage

```
bar(foo);
```